# Download location of JDEdwards EnterpriseOne 8.12 Standalone Demo

Tags: jdedwards

Where from I can download JDEdwards EnterpriseOne 8.12 Standalone Demo. Please do not say just edelivery.oracle.com. I searched lot in edelivery.oracle.com, but could not find **8.12** ?

Answer (score 1):

Start here:
edelivery.oracle.com

Search on:
Product Pack: JD Edwards EnterpriseOne
Platform: Microsoft Windows 32 bit (even if for 64 bit!)

Find the item with description:
JD Edwards EnterpriseOne 9.0 Application Update 2 Media Pack

Click on it and see that there are 4 files to download.  They are about 5 GB in total, and titled:
JD Edwards EnterpriseOne 9.0 Update 2 and 8.98.4 Standalone with English and Language Translation (1/4)
... and so on up to (4/4)

This post walks you through all this:  http://www.deepeshmd.com/enterpriseone/jd-edwards-enterpriseone-9-0-2-standalone-installation/